# Running java program without ide

Tags: java, ide

I am making a simple program for my class, and my teacher will run it. I want to run it without using an IDE or the command line interface. Basically, I want a beginner friendly way of running it, something my teacher can do easily without navigating through a complicated procedure. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Pack it as an executable jar?!

Comment: "something my teacher can do easily without navigating through a complicated procedure" If your teacher cannot run it from the command line, that's strange.

Comment: @peter.petrov The Teacher must know the main-class then, where do he get it? From source.

Comment: @ peter.petrov: Well my teacher is not a programmer so she cannot type all the commands.

Comment: @PeterRader From a 3-lines long README.TXT maybe.

Comment: @peter.petrov Documentation? Nobody reads handbooks anymore. I spend days by writing handbooks and nobody read them. I realy like you! You give me hope that someone will read my handbooks one day. You realy made my day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try packaging it as a .jar file

Here's how to do it without an IDE: http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/createjar.html

and how to do it in Eclipse: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mE3rbtKm-pk

Comment: thanks a lot! This really helped. So after packaging it as a runnable jar, will it be openable with a single click? And what program will it open in? Also, I use JCrator, is there a way to do it in this IDE?

Comment: @ShubhankarDas the Java Virtual Machine will execute it. So the JVM has to be installed on the target machine.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Export option of `Eclipse` (If it's your `IDE` of course) and choose "Runable `Jar` file"